# Is there any way to find Power-on-self-test (POST) logs/results?

Tags: linux, hardware, boot, bios

During the Linux boot process, is there any way to see what POST tests were run and the results? Do they only get reported if there was a failure?

Fairly new to Linux and understanding the boot process, would really like to understand the output of the boot screen and what is going on.

Comment: no, because POST is "the bios", and runs before linux has even STARTED to boot up. there's no practical place to store any post results, because the bios has no knowledge of how/where the data should be stored. the bios chip has only limited storage, the OS will possibly wipe memory where the results are stored as part of its own startup, etc...

Comment: If I am connected via serial port, once I power on, does BIOS get output to the screen at all? I should mentioned these are embedded devices running Linux.

Comment: on "business" class machines with certain management features, there is a serial console available. on your average homebrew/home pc, no.

Comment: So since I have serial console available, will BIOS (POST tests) output be seen?

Comment: probably not. just because a computer has port X, doesn't mean anything will be output to that port during boot. you need extra hardware for that, particularly a cpu that supports something like intel's vpro.

Answer (score 1):

If the computer booted, all POST tests passed. If the computer did not boot, they failed.

Keep in mind that POST tests are simple read/write tests of a few memory locations, and some chipset registers.  They are not really useful as a hardware diagnostic.

Comment: I mean I understand that much, was more curious as to the different POST tests being run by various BIOS. I mean I know they run, but what exactly, they must be defined somewhere.

Comment: That varies from BIOS to BIOS. Some motherboard/PC manufacturers publish a list of POST codes which will tell you what tests are run.